# After installing Ubuntu 16.04, "Operating System not found" error is coming

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I already had Windows and Ubuntu 12.04 on my system. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 after erasing 12.04 using USB. On restarting, I was getting some grub error so I followed the steps described on this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I restarted the system again and now I am getting "Operating System not found" error. The generated report is uploaded here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDaygQnkm-CMllveXcyai1OaVU/view